# Open pdf file in browser using php?

Tags: php, android, apache

When I execute below code on localhost but pdf not open.

PDF open failed messege will be displayed. Any problem this code?

```
 <?php
  //$file = $_POST["image"];
  //$filename = $_POST["fname"];

  $file = '/home/Desktop/GH-07/hospitalpdf/10004.pdf';
  $filename = 'fit.pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  //header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=''.$filename.''');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    @readfile($file);


?>
```

Comment: Use error reporting and find out http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Thanks. I will check

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to output your file (@readfile), is preventing all possible errors from being printed.
Check here: http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Either remove the error control operator (@), either use a different way to print your pdf file, and try have control over the debugging phase:

`$output = file_get_contents( $file );
 echo $output;`